# RxJava onErrorResumeNext calls java.io.InterrupedIOException

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have problem with RxJava onErrorResumeNext operator.
I want to get location, then get data from server (with Retrofit) depends on location, but if no location(error: Sequence does not contain elements), I want to get data from server with another Observable (which does not depend on location). I tried to use onErrorResumeNext operator, but get "java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted".

Code before adding onErrorResumeNext - works good

```
LocationService.getUpdatedOrLastKnownLocation(getContext()))
            .flatMap(location -> RestService.getPostsAround(location,0,10)) //offset = 0, limit = 10;
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Code with onErrorResumeNext - throws Exception

```
LocationService.getUpdatedOrLastKnownLocation(getContext()))
            .flatMap(location -> RestService.getPostsAround(location,0,10)) //offset = 0, limit = 10;
            .onErrorResumeNext(RestService.getPostsByMapProjection(googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Stacktrace:

```
07-27 22:33:58.384 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
07-27 22:33:58.384 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
07-27 22:33:58.385 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:77)
07-27 22:33:58.385 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
07-27 22:33:58.385 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
07-27 22:33:58.386 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.finishRequest(Http1xStream.java:159)
07-27 22:33:58.386 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:721)
07-27 22:33:58.387 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:81)
07-27 22:33:58.387 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:708)
07-27 22:33:58.389 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:563)
07-27 22:33:58.389 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:241)
07-27 22:33:58.389 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
07-27 22:33:58.391 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
07-27 22:33:58.392 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
07-27 22:33:58.392 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
07-27 22:33:58.392 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
07-27 22:33:58.392 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
07-27 22:33:58.393 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
07-27 22:33:58.394 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
07-27 22:33:58.394 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
07-27 22:33:58.394 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
07-27 22:33:58.395 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
07-27 22:33:58.395 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
07-27 22:33:58.396 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFlattenIterable.call(OnSubscribeFlattenIterable.java:65)
07-27 22:33:58.396 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFlattenIterable.call(OnSubscribeFlattenIterable.java:37)
07-27 22:33:58.396 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8460)
07-27 22:33:58.398 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:141)
07-27 22:33:58.398 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:266)
07-27 22:33:58.398 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:810)
07-27 22:33:58.400 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:571)
07-27 22:33:58.400 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:560)
07-27 22:33:58.400 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:276)
07-27 22:33:58.401 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onError(OperatorMap.java:85)
07-27 22:33:58.403 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:266)
07-27 22:33:58.403 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:810)
07-27 22:33:58.403 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:571)
07-27 22:33:58.404 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:560)
07-27 22:33:58.404 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:844)
07-27 22:33:58.404 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onError(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:59)
07-27 22:33:58.405 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:264)
07-27 22:33:58.406 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:207)
07-27 22:33:58.406 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
07-27 22:33:58.406 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
07-27 22:33:58.406 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-27 22:33:58.407 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
07-27 22:33:58.407 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-27 22:33:58.407 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-27 22:33:58.407 18632-18632/com.blacksea.plamobi W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you post how this is creating Observable? `RestService.getPostsByMapProjection(googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()` does it observeOn() new thread?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But if I add it, nothing changes. Observable created by retrofit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If retrofit2 is used, its observables do not change thread they operate on, so all chain until subscribeOn() operates on single thread from io scheduler. Apparently error from `RestService.getPostsAround` sets interrupted flag for that thread, and okio chokes on that in `RestService.getPostsByMapProjection` . You can try to add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` after `RestService.getPostsByMapProjection` in `onErrorResumeNext()`.

Comment: perfect, `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` resolved problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the `java.io.InterruptedIOException` is a red herring, as it usually means that some *other* thread unsubscribed, and any threads that are running (f.e. network requests) get interrupted.

In your case, `RestService.getPostsByMapProjection` gets called every time whether or not there is an error, which might not be behavior that you want; consider wrapping it in an `Observable.defer()`

Comment: I changed code to: `.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.defer(() -> RestService.getPostsByMapProjection(googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion())))`, but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use max concurrency on your flatMap just to be sure that you´re not having any concurrent issue

```
@Beta
public final <R> Observable<R> flatMap(Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> func, int maxConcurrent) {
    if (getClass() == ScalarSynchronousObservable.class) {
        return ((ScalarSynchronousObservable<T>)this).scalarFlatMap(func);
    }
    return merge(map(func), maxConcurrent);
}
```

In your code

```
    LocationService.getUpdatedOrLastKnownLocation(getContext()))
        .flatMap(location -> RestService.getPostsAround(location,0,10),1) //offset = 0, limit = 10;
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(subscriber);
```